# Partition and Filter Queries in Tabular model SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I am very new to Tabular model.How does creating the partion (to a  once of the transaction data table)and applying filter queries to each partition beniftd the Query performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230810.aspx

FYI: Partitions improve query performance by narrowing the amount of data supposed to be scanned to get the result.